# IllegalStateException: No LoginService for FormAuthenticator Jetty

Tags: jetty, jaas, jetty-9

I'm configuring a custom JAAS Login module in Jetty.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.AbstractLoginModule;

public class HybridLoginModule extends AbstractLoginModule
```

I add the file in: `jetty-9.4.8/etc/login.conf`

```
hybridRealm {
  net.sf.jkniv.jaas.jetty.HybridLoginModule required
}
```

Enable the jaas in: `jetty-9.4.8/start.ini`

```
--module=jaas
jetty.jaas.login.conf=etc/login.conf
```

And config JAAS JAASLoginService in `jetty-9.4.8/etc/jetty-webapp.xml`

```
  <Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
        <Set name="name">Hybrid JAAS Realm</Set>
        <Set name="LoginModuleName">hybridRealm</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
```

But when I start jetty server `java -jar  start.jar` the exception is throw

**IllegalStateException: No LoginService for FormAuthenticator**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator@25084a1e in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@156b88f5    
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.setConfiguration(LoginAuthenticator.java:76)    
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator.setConfiguration(FormAuthenticator.java:131)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image][**The jetty documentation it's ambiguous**](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/jaas-support.html), to solution the configuration problem set the `realm-name` property from **web.xml** file to same value from `<Set name="Name">` proprety, no `<Set name="LoginModuleName">`.

**web.xml file:**

```
<realm-name>xyzREALM</realm-name>
```

**jetty-webapp.xml file:**

```
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
  <Set name="Name">xyzREALM</Set>
  <Set name="LoginModuleName">hybridRealm</Set>
</New>
```